# Thinkpad Edge e320 thermal sensors description

Tags: thinkpad, lm-sensors

I have a quite specific question concerning description of thermal sensors of my  Thinkpad Edge E320 notebook.

I have a Debian Linux installed with lm_sensors package and running command *sensors* show eight different values without any description (temp1 through temp6). I would like to know which one is which (CPU, GPU, HDDd, etc.)

Using Google I didn't find any specific material concerning this exact model.
Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long ago but it seems there's still no documentation at all, so this is what I've found out by testing (temp increases on load) so far:

- 0 - CPU
- 2 - GPU
- 3 - Unknown (really strange behaviour, values from 0 to 7 - any ideas?)
- 5 - Chipset
- 6 - Battery
- 8 - Chipset

There is NO sensor for hard disk temperature